# AngularJS 1.6 pagination not displaying

Tags: jquery, angularjs, binding, angularjs-scope

I'm new with Angular, and I'm building off of a previous tutorial created by Jason Watmore (http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/01/31/angularjs-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google) on pagination.

I've gotten pretty close to making it work, but I'm obviously missing some critical step(s).

My sample app will go out, fetch the data, and return it, but it's not displaying in the div on the page, and the pagination isn't working (as expected).

**Index.html**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contentWrapper">
     <div data-ng-controller="searchBtnCtrl as vm">
  <h3>Search:</h3>
  <input id="searchQuery" type="text" placeholder="enter your search query here" data-ng-model="searchInput" />

  <button id="searchBtn" data-ng-click="performSearch()">SEARCH</button>

  <div id="searchResults">
    <!-- items being paged -->
    <div ng-repeat="post in vm.posts"><a href='{{post.title}}' alt='{{post.title}}'>{{post.title}}</a><br />{{post.body}}</div>

    <!-- pager -->
    <ul ng-if="vm.pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
      <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === 1}">
        <a ng-click="vm.setPage(1)">First</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === 1}">
        <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-repeat="page in vm.pager.pages" ng-class="{active:vm.pager.currentPage === page}">
        <a ng-click="vm.setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === vm.pager.totalPages}">
        <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === vm.pager.totalPages}">
        <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular
        .module('testApp', [])
        .factory('PagerService', PagerService);

    //controllers
        app.controller('searchBtnCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'PagerService', function ($scope, $http, PagerService) {
        $scope.performSearch = function() {
            console.log('clicked');
            $('#searchResults').html('');

            var vm = this;

            $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function (response) {
                $scope.responseData = response.data;
                console.log($scope.responseData.length);
                console.log($scope.responseData);

                vm.itemsToDisplay = $scope.responseData; // array of items to be paged
                vm.pager = {};
                vm.setPage = setPage;

                initController();

                function initController() {
                    // initialize to page 1
                    vm.setPage(1);
                }

                function setPage(page) {
                    if (page < 1 || page > vm.pager.totalPages) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // get pager object from service
                    vm.pager = PagerService.GetPager(vm.itemsToDisplay.length, page);

                    // get current page of items
                    vm.items = vm.itemsToDisplay.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);
                }

            });
        }
    }]);

    function PagerService() {
        // service definition
        var service = {};

        service.GetPager = GetPager;

        return service;

        // service implementation
        function GetPager(totalItems, currentPage, pageSize) {
            // default to first page
            currentPage = currentPage || 1;

            // default page size is 10
            pageSize = pageSize || 10;

            // calculate total pages
            var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

            var startPage, endPage;
            if (totalPages <= 10) {
                // less than 10 total pages so show all
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
                if (currentPage <= 6) {
                    startPage = 1;
                    endPage = 10;
                } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                    startPage = totalPages - 9;
                    endPage = totalPages;
                } else {
                    startPage = currentPage - 5;
                    endPage = currentPage + 4;
                }
            }

            // calculate start and end item indexes
            var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
            var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

            // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
            var pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

            // return object with all pager properties required by the view
            return {
                totalItems: totalItems,
                currentPage: currentPage,
                pageSize: pageSize,
                totalPages: totalPages,
                startPage: startPage,
                endPage: endPage,
                startIndex: startIndex,
                endIndex: endIndex,
                pages: pages
            };
        }
    }



})();
```

And here's a code pen to the project. **For this example, ignore the searchbox and just press the search button to active the script.**

https://codepen.io/code_nick/pen/gvQJLX?editors=1010

and also the debug version. If you view this version with the console open, you'll see that it's counting the number of items returned (good) and returning the data as objects (also good), it's just not showing up on the page (bummer #1) and the pagination isn't working (bummer #2).

https://s.codepen.io/code_nick/debug/gvQJLX/PBMNWxowdewr

I think it's probably a scope issue, but as scope in angular still gives me issues, maybe the data isn't available when the ng-repeat fires in the html?

Comment: in ng-repeat, where are you getting this from? `vm.posts` . there is no such object in ur JS.

Comment: why are you clearing the html that contains ur ng-repeat and pages? `$('#searchResults').html('');`

Comment: So that in each additional search, it starts with an empty div. However the pagination may take care of that, so maybe it's not necessary to do?

Comment: ng-repeat has two-way binding. It will update automatically when the object changes.

Comment: ...Of course it will..geez.. silly me.. I'm still getting my head around some of Angular's concepts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 3 things which were not right.

1. You need to store `this` reference of the controller outside the
   `performSearch` function.
2. You shouldn't be replacing the html inside the `searchResults` to empty
3. You are using `vm.posts` in the `ng-repeat` but `vm.items` holds the posts

With all the fixes, the final code should look like this

**JS**

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module("testApp", []).factory("PagerService", PagerService);

  //controllers
  app.controller("searchBtnCtrl", [
    "$scope",
    "$http",
    "PagerService",
    function($scope, $http, PagerService) {
      var vm = this;
      $scope.performSearch = function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        $(".post").remove();

        $http
          .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.responseData = response.data;
            console.log($scope.responseData.length);
            console.log($scope.responseData);

            vm.itemsToDisplay = $scope.responseData; // array of items to be paged
            vm.pager = {};
            vm.setPage = setPage;

            initController();

            function initController() {
              // initialize to page 1
              vm.setPage(1);
            }

            function setPage(page) {
              if (page < 1 || page > vm.pager.totalPages) {
                return;
              }

              // get pager object from service
              vm.pager = PagerService.GetPager(vm.itemsToDisplay.length, page);

              // get current page of items
              vm.posts = vm.itemsToDisplay.slice(
                vm.pager.startIndex,
                vm.pager.endIndex + 1
              );
            }
          });
      };
    }
  ]);

  function PagerService() {
    // service definition
    var service = {};

    service.GetPager = GetPager;

    return service;

    // service implementation
    function GetPager(totalItems, currentPage, pageSize) {
      // default to first page
      currentPage = currentPage || 1;

      // default page size is 10
      pageSize = pageSize || 10;

      // calculate total pages
      var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

      var startPage, endPage;
      if (totalPages <= 10) {
        // less than 10 total pages so show all
        startPage = 1;
        endPage = totalPages;
      } else {
        // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
        if (currentPage <= 6) {
          startPage = 1;
          endPage = 10;
        } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
          startPage = totalPages - 9;
          endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
          startPage = currentPage - 5;
          endPage = currentPage + 4;
        }
      }

      // calculate start and end item indexes
      var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
      var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

      // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
      var pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

      // return object with all pager properties required by the view
      return {
        totalItems: totalItems,
        currentPage: currentPage,
        pageSize: pageSize,
        totalPages: totalPages,
        startPage: startPage,
        endPage: endPage,
        startIndex: startIndex,
        endIndex: endIndex,
        pages: pages
      };
    }
  }
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div data-ng-controller="searchBtnCtrl as vm">
      <h3>Search:</h3>
      <input id="searchQuery" type="text" placeholder="enter your search query here" data-ng-model="searchInput" />

      <button id="searchBtn" data-ng-click="performSearch()">SEARCH</button>

      <div id="searchResults">
        <!-- items being paged --> 
        <div ng-repeat="post in vm.posts"> 
          <span class="post"><a href='{{post.title}}' alt='{{post.title}}'>{{post.title}}</a><br />{{post.body}}</span></div>

        <!-- pager -->
        <ul ng-if="vm.pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
          <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === 1}">
            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(1)">First</a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === 1}">
            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="page in vm.pager.pages" ng-class="{active:vm.pager.currentPage === page}">
            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === vm.pager.totalPages}">
            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === vm.pager.totalPages}">
            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, I had a few boneheaded things I did wrong, but thanks to Swain and lilo, it's working now. Much appreciated! :)